# Word count frequency: removing stopwords

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following list of words frequency generated by the code below.

```
Frequency
the 3
15  5
18  1
a   1
2020    4
... ...
house   1
apartment   1
hotel   5
pool    1
swimming    1
```

The code is

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Sentences'])
w_freq = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]

w_df=pd.DataFrame(w_freq, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency'])
w_df
```

I would like to remove the stopwords from the the list of words above (not in the column of my dataframe, but just in the output, creating a new variable in case it would be needed).

I have tried with `w_df =[w for w in w_df if not w in stop_words]` but it gave me `['Frequency']` as output. 
I think this happens because it is not a list. 
Could you please tell me how to remove stopwords (numbers included) from there?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) has a parameter that *does that for you*. You can feed it a custom list of stopwords, or set it to `english`, a built-in stop word list. Here's an example:

```
s = pd.Series('Just a random sentence with more than one stopword')

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), 
                                  analyzer='word', 
                                  stop_words='english')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(s)
w_freq = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
w_df=pd.DataFrame(w_freq, 
                  index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), 
                  columns=['Frequency'])
print(w_df)

          Frequency
just              1
random            1
sentence          1
stopword          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, your approach wasn't all that wrong. You needed just a minor change.

```
w_df = [w for w in w_df.index if not w in stop_words]
```

Your problem was simply that, in the list comprehension, you iterated over the dataframe itself rather than the tokens which are in its index. This would also return the desired result.